# Method setAttribute() - pass parameters from servlet to Javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp

I've created a servlet where doPost() method sends arraylist named ***facultyList*** as a parameter of setAttribute() method to jsp page. Find out the code below:

```
package com.wikamp.servlets;

@WebServlet("/AdminLogin")
public class AdminLogin extends HttpServlet {
    private AdminDAO adminDAO;
    private FacultyDAO facultyDAO;
    private Admin admin;
    private Faculty faculty;

    private int adminNo;
    private String passwordAcc;

    public void init() {
        facultyDAO = new FacultyDAO();
    }

    private void facultyList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
        HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
        ArrayList<Faculty> facultyList = facultyDAO.getFaculties();
        httpSession.setAttribute("facultyList", facultyList);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request,response);
        try {
            adminDAO = new AdminDAO();

            adminNo = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("adminNo"));
            passwordAcc = request.getParameter("passAcc");
            admin = adminDAO.getAdmin(adminNo,passwordAcc);

            if (admin!=null && (admin.getADMIN_ID()>1 && admin.getPASSWORD_ACC()!=null)) {
                HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();
                httpSession.setAttribute("adminNo",adminNo);

                try {
                    facultyList(request,response);
                }
                catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                response.sendRedirect("AdminDashboard.jsp?adminNo="+adminNo);
            }
            else {
                response.sendRedirect("None");
            }
        }
        catch (NullPointerException | SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

In jsp file I implemented some jstl code (***foreach loop***) to show the whole table which presents names of faculties and number of students who belong to each faculty of a university.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Faculty</th>
        <th>Number of Students</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <c:forEach var="fac" items="${facultyList}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <c:out value="${fac.facultyName}" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <c:out value="${fac.studentsNo}" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div id="piechart" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px;"></div>

</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/FacultyPieChart.js"></script>
</html>
```

Then I use google charts to present the same data on a pie chart. The chart is generated by javascript file as below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    var facultyStats = [];
    console.log(facultyStats)

    var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    table.bgColor = "Yellow";

    var td = table.getElementsByTagName("td");

    for (var i = 0; i < td.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            facultyStats[i] = td[i].innerHTML.trim();
            td[i].style.background = "LightBlue";
        }
        else {
            facultyStats[i] = td[i];
            td[i].style.background = "Orange";
        }
    }

    function drawChart() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Faculty', 'Number of students'],
            [facultyStats[0].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[1].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[2].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[3].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[4].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[5].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[6].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[7].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[8].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[9].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[10].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[11].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[12].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[13].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
            [facultyStats[14].toString(), parseInt(facultyStats[15].innerHTML.trim(), 10)],
        ]);

        var options = {
            title: 'Number of students per faculty (in %)'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
});
```

The following screenshoot presents the final result of my code, pie char retrieving data from the html table, according to the following JS code:

*var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

var td = table.getElementsByTagName("td");*

[image]

The main idea is to pass the arraylist from the servlet to javascript file directly. I would like to get rid of html table which is useless for me and let javascript code retrieve data directly from the arraylist.

I tried to put foreach loop to JS file, but it does not work, because JS does not recognize jstl code.

Comment: Does anyone know the question?